# Drop down with checkboxes and indentation

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to implement an HTML dropdown (using the select option html tags) in which every entry has its own checkbox plus an optional indentation (to mimic a hierarchical layout).

I'm using AngularJS and I managed to have the drop down work with a simple list using `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <label>Test dropdown</label>
   <br>
   <select>
      <option ng-repeat="x in myList">{{x}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Now, given what I've got, the next step is to have entry indentation (yes/no) and a checkbox (selected/unselected). How can I add such elements? Shall I augment my array with such informations (e.g. a list of objects each one containing the actual entry name, the checkbox status and a boolean for the indentation)

Comment: do you have any expected output screen??

Comment: Check this out https://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main